# Cannot access scala value/variable inside RDD foreach function (Null)

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, rdd, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Spark Structured Streaming job that needs to use the `rdd.forEach` inside the `forEachBatch` function as per the bellow code:

```
val tableName = "ddb_table"

df
    .writeStream
    .foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, _: Long) =>
      batchDF
        .rdd
        .foreach(
          r => updateDDB(r, tableName, "key")
        )

      curDate= LocalDate.now().toString.replaceAll("-", "/")
      prevDate= LocalDate.now().minusDays(1).toString.replaceAll("-", "/")
    }
    .outputMode(OutputMode.Append)
    .option("checkpointLocation", "checkPointDir")
    .start()
    .awaitTermination()
```

What happens is that the `tableName` variable is not recognized inside the `rdd.forEach` function because the call to the DynamoDB API inside the `updateDDB` raises an exception stating that the tableName cannot be null.

The issue is clearly in the rdd/forEach and the way it works with variables. I read some things about broadcast variables, but I don't have enough experience working with RDDs and Spark in a much lower level to be sure what is the way to go.

Some notes:

1. I need this to be inside the `forEachBatch` function because I need to update other variables apart from this write to DDB (in this case the `curDate` and `prevDate` variables)
2. The code runs successfully when I pass the `tableName` parameter directly in the function call.
3. I have one class that extends the `ForEachWriter` that works ok when using the `forEach` instead of the `forEachBatch`, but as stated in point 1) I need to use the second because I need to update several things at a streaming batch time.

Comment: Rdd fors not work with str streaming

Comment: That's not the issue. The use case works if I pass the tableName value directly, e.g. "updateDDB(r, "ddb_table", "key")". If I use a variable instead of the specific value it seems that the job doesn't recognize it.

Comment: well i follow the manuals, i think that is a good policy